# Not able to clear data/refresh data in Edit block while switching between Steps in Omniscript

Tags: salesforce

The scenario is-
In Omniscript in Step1- doing Account Search,there I have given 'Retail' as Input. After clicking on Search an apex class is running and returning 4 records. We are showing these records in Edit block in Step2 in Omniscript. Now from Step2 I clicked on previous button which redirected me to Step1. There I have removed 'Retail' as input and given 'first' as input. Again apex class is running and returning 3 records and is being shown in edit block. Now the issue is the edit block is not getting refreshed/cleared. It is showing 3 records of 2nd search along with 4th record of 1st search.

If 1st search have result around 10 records and 2nd search is having 5 records, then 5 records of 2nd search are being replaced in the same edit block. I'm seeing 5 records of 2nd search along with remaining results of previous search.

Expected is I should see only the current search results in edit block.

I tried enabling Allow Clear in edit block Properties and in between the step1 and step2, placed a step value action where the Element Name & Value are EditBlock1(name of edit block in Step2) = null.

Still the issue is not resolved.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We were also facing similar issue, on click of previous button we add Navigation Action to restart OmniScript but it did not help, Then we renamed Next Button to previous button and added Navigation action to restart the OmniScript then started clearing data for previous search data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setValues in between the steps(conditionally as well). In case you want the previous data to be gone set the element to empty. Or append the values as per your requirement.